# how to deselect uitableview cells when app is starting in swift

Tags: ios, swift

This is My Code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    if (selectedTypes!).contains(key) {
        selectedTypes = selectedTypes.filter({$0 != key})
    } else {
        selectedTypes.append(key)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

I am deselecting cells on second line but it's not working

Comment: What do you do when you start your app?

Comment: All cells are selected initially but i want to deselect cells when i launch my app

Comment: This method will be called when you select a cell not for deselecting.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK does not automatically select all cells when your app starts.

If all tableView cells are being selected, this is happening because of something in your code (or a third-party control or library).

Also `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does not get called when a row is programmatically selected.  It's only called when the user selects a row, so the approach you hope will work is not going to automatically deselect any selected rows.

Answer (score 1):

By default not a single cell get selected. There must be something in your logic which makes it selected.

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath get called when user touch the row.
```